# Знаки препинания при инверсии в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, тире, спп, инверсия

Можно ли сформулировать правило, по которому при инверсии можно/нужно ставить   тире между частями СПП?

Пример:
*Если выбор не будет сделан ― деньгами автоматически займётся государственная управляющая компания.* [Вероника Сивкова. На что тратит деньги Пенсионный фонд (2003) // «Аргументы и факты», 2003.06.04]

А полагаю, что обычный порядок слов таков (главная часть стоит на первом 
месте):
*Деньгами автоматически займётся государственная управляющая компания, если выбор не будет сделан*.

Дополнение.
Нашел у Розенталя:

[§ 111. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html)

> При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные   и з ъ я с н и т е л ь н ы е   (дополнительные и подлежащные), реже  у с л о в н ы е   и   у с т у п и т е л ь н ы е,  стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут отделяться от него не запятой, а тире, например: Буде спросит кто о чём – молчи… (Пушкин); Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять (Гоголь); Что она натура честная – это мне ясно… (Тургенев); Пускай, как хотят, тиранят, пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут – я воли своей не отдам (Салтыков-Щедрин); Взгляну ли вдаль, взгляну ли на тебя – и в сердце свет какой-то загорится (Фет); Мне выслали какие-то книги, но какие именно – не знаю.

Comment: Почему это у вас обычный порядок, а там инверсия?

Comment: @Niemand Вы хототе спросить, почему я называю такой порядок обычным?  Так он воспринимается. Так его некоторые называют — обычным или нейтральным. "...при нейтральном порядке расположения частей должно быть наоборот: главная часть должна предшествовать зависимой" (https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=71). Но я не настаиваю на такой терминологии. Не в ней дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Позиция придаточного изучается в грамматике СПП. В предложениях одного вида она может быть свободной, в предложениях другого – фиксированной.

Позиция является **свободной**, когда возможна перестановка придаточного,  при этом **постпозиция** придаточного действительно считается **основной (нейтральной).**

Это объясняется тем, что главное придаточное в этом случае  не зависит от придаточного, которое можно  просто убрать из предложения.

Например: *Гулять не пойдем, так как холодно.* Это чисто причинное отношение между главным и придаточным предложениями.

**В препозиции** отношения становятся причинно-следственными, взаимообусловленными: *Так как холодно, гулять не пойдем.*

Это нужно учитывать при построении сложного предложения. Итак, препозиция придаточного увеличивает его значимость, но при этом по-прежнему ставится **запятая**, которая является основным знаком в СПП. **Тире** – неосновной знак, он обозначает увеличенную паузу.

Что нам это дает? Придаточное в препозиции еще в большей степени подчеркивается, получает дополнительное выделение. Иногда это связано с его семантикой, а иногда со структурой. Например,  нужно обозначить границу между предложениями, одно из которых назывное,  или в предложение есть местоимение *это* и т.д.

Comment: А нет ли особого подхода, когда инверсии подвергается СПП с союзом *если*? Ведь при инверсии естественно поставить сложный союз "если...то", а у нас "то" как будто потерялось. Мне кажется, что именно поэтому так естественно тут тире. Прав ли я?

Comment: Здесь я могу только  высказать свое мнение.  Мне кажется, что тире  и указательный элемент ТО (в союзе ЕСЛИ...ТО) выполняют одинаковую функцию, дополнительно обозначая взаимообусловленность предложений. В то же время элемент ТО и запятая  скорее используются в распространенных СПП, чтобы определить границы главного и придаточного, а тире - в коротких или разноструктурных СПП.

Comment: А вариант без ТО, но с запятой (Если выбор не будет сделан, деньгами автоматически займётся государственная управляющая компания) легитимен? Если да, то как определить,что предпочтительней: запятая или тире?

Comment: Мне кажется,  что в этом предложении тире связано с контекстом. Надо сделать выбор. А если выбор не будет сделан - делами займется компания. То есть присутствует значение противопоставления. При отсутствии такого контекста ставится  обычная запятая, то есть необходимости в увеличенной паузе нет.